# Cross site scripting: DOM

Tags: javascript, java, html

```
var path = document.location.pathname;

if (path.lastIndexOf("/") != 0){
  path= path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
}

open("default.htm?startat=" + path + document.location.search, "_top");
```

Which is the best way to prevent cross site scripting?
I am using this code I am trying to find a way to validate the data coming from url. But I do not know what kind of validation should I do.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually server-side validations there are many type of xss attack which is the best way to handle them is keep your codes update and checking inputs from the server